# PHP sessions getting unset

Tags: php, session, unset

I'm using a session variable to store login data. Locally, everything works smooth, it logs in nicely and doesn't log out inbetween pages.

But when I put the same files on the server, for some reason I get logged out. I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933441/sessions-get-messed-up-on-external-host) post, and tried using following code to prevent caching of dynamic pages:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Though that doesn't seem to work. Are there any other possible solutions to this problem?

**Edit:** Note that `session_start()` is on every page.

**Edit 2:** I did a little further investigation and it appears some of my links link to `www.mysite.com` when on the `mysite.com`. Going to this new page makes that the `$_SESSION[]` vars aren't set, and when returning to the previous page with the back button you can see the `$_SESSION[]` is still set.

Comment: Have you started session on all pages

Comment: Go to the root of the problem: Investigate the request/response headers while moving around your pages. If sessions are disappearing then you will see it there.

Comment: @ManishJangir: the sessions are started on every page yes.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: How would I do that?

Comment: @arbitter: Look at the *Network* tab of your developer tools, it should be there.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I did a little further investigation and it appears some of my links link to `www.mysite.com` when on the `mysite.com`. Going to this new page makes that the `$_SESSION[]` vars aren't set, and when returning to the previous page with the back button you can see the `$_SESSION[]` is still set. How do I solve this?

Comment: @arbitter: Make sure error reporting is enabled, is it possible that you're sending output by accident before starting the session? It's possible that on your local environment there's an output buffer keeping output from being sent, and on your live server there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions use cookies, so when you change domains (www.site.com to site.com) those cookies aren't being transmitted.

Set up your webserver to have one canonical url, and redirect everyone to that (for example, standardize on site.com, redirect www.site.com to site.com).

This is how I handle redirects in apache:

```
ServerAlias www.site.com my.site.com site.net www.site.net sites.com www.sites.com site.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !=site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I prefer site.com over www.site.com, unless you're doing something different on the two of them making people type an extra four characters seems worthless. My (lame) understanding of SEO is that you're better off picking one than having duplicate content at two urls (site.com/stuff and www.site.com/stuff)

Comment: Are there any advantages to have www.mysite.com over mysite.com or in the other way around? What would be the easiest way to implement this?