# Session data gets confused on web host

Tags: php, session, unset

Messed up = I log-in to my account, if I change page, I'm in another random account from the database (but never my account again). This only happens on external host, local host works fine.

I have `session_start()` on all pages, and I only set session data in one file, which is not included anywhere on any page once the person is logged.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933441/sessions-get-messed-up-on-external-host) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624567/php-sessions-getting-unset?lq=1)

Tried this on every page

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

And my .htaccess redirects website.com to www.website.com, so the URL is unique.

I checked my code, and I don't change the session data anywhere after the user is logged, so I don't know what is causing this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that this is not a caching issue as in the first question you linked to?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I did. I checked the HTTP Headers of every page, and none of them is being cached. Also, if matters: the PHPSESSID stays the same.

Comment: Do you have access to the temp dir where session files are stored on the server? (Assuming the default PHP session mechanism is used.) Trying to watch what files are created, when they are modified and what they contain might possibly shed some more light on this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access. I use hostgator, and I only have access to my /home folder. According to php.ini config, the session is saved on /tmp. And yes, it's default PHP session... Do you think I could try using another host to see if the problem persist, once that works on localhost?

Comment: _“According to php.ini config, the session is saved on /tmp”_ – for all users of the hosting server …? That could be the problem right there then. Try to set the [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) config value to a path inside your user dir where you have write permission. (Can be done using `ini_set` if you have no other access to config, but must happen before `session_start` every time.)

Comment: I changed the `session.save_path` to the `tmp` folder inside my /home folder, but didn't solve it. But now I have access to the session files, so I noticed that they are created already with another user from the db.

Answer (score 0):

I compared the php.ini from my localhost and the one from the host and  the `register_globals` was `Off` on the localhost, but `On` on the server.

So I disabled `register_globals`on the server and it works now.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don’t say your script is still using `session_register` …?

Comment: No. Hostgator has a php.ini quickconfig on cpanel, which I activated, but `register_globals` was activated too and I didn't noticed it once nobody uses `register_globals` anymore.

Comment: Yes, but `register_globals=on` should only be able to overwrite session values, when `session_register` is used to save values into the session.